# Batch errorlevel is not working properly

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, copy, errorlevel

so i have really problems with the ERRORLEVEL of batch. Its just not working for me.
I have a big own ms build batch script and i always get 0 back from ERRORLEVEL, whatever I do (eg. msbuild, tf get, tf checkout, copy, xcopy,...)

so i did a small example to post it here:

```
@echo off
set Update=1
IF %Update% == 1 (
    echo.
    set /p "=- Copy stuff..." <NUL
    xcopy /R /Y C:\test\2.lib   C:\test1
    if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (echo FAILED!) ELSE (echo SUCCEED!)
    echo -^> done
    pause
)
```

so its always returning succeed and printing 0 when i do: echo %ERRORLEVEL%

can you please help me with that? I really would like to use that errorlevel

Answer (score 4):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) here or to use [`IF ERRORLEVEL`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) :

```
@echo off
set Update=1
IF %Update% == 1 (
    echo.
    set /p "=- Copy stuff..." <NUL
    xcopy /R /Y C:\test\2.lib   C:\test1
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo FAILED!) ELSE (echo SUCCEED!)
    echo -^> done
    pause
)
```

with `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` you can check if the errorlevel is *1 or bigger* .

Comment: ah great it is working!! thanks a lot!! so this its checking all errorlevels >= 1 then? to make it better readable I thought i will try: IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (echo SUCCEED!) ELSE (echo FAILED!) but this is not working unfortunately. do you know why?

Comment: @Scorpion because `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` will catch errorlevels bigger than 0 which includes 1,2...

Answer (score 1):

As npocmaka says, you have a delayed expansion issue.

An alternative is to ditch ERRORLEVEL and use the `&&` and `||` conditional command concatenation operators instead.

```
@echo off
set Update=1
IF %Update% == 1 (
    echo.
    set /p "=- Copy stuff..." <NUL
    xcopy /R /Y C:\test\2.lib   C:\test1 && (echo SUCCEED!) || (echo FAILED!)
    echo -^> done
    pause
)
```

***Edit showing use of multiple lines***

```
@echo off
set Update=1
IF %Update% == 1 (
    echo.
    set /p "=- Copy stuff..." <NUL
    xcopy /R /Y C:\test\2.lib   C:\test1 && (
        echo First success command
        echo SUCCEED!
    ) || (
        echo First failure command
        echo FAILED!
    )
    echo -^> done
    pause
)
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative! but since the commands i want to check are usually much longer, I will do it in a separate line in oder do make it more readable :)

Comment: @Scorpion - ??? The number of lines has nothing to do with the difference in technique. You can still use multiple lines with this technique.

Comment: thanks for your efford! Sorry, I didn´t say it proper before, but I meant that its just (for me) less easy to read and I think also for colleagues when they will go through my batch. Thats the reason why I stick with the solution of npocmaka. but you also got a +1 from me :)